# Best free graph database for order of 500 million nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j community server edition. It takes 1 minute to find nodes connected across 3 layers. Are there other free graph databases which can perform this type of query faster. The dataset is smaller than RAM of the PC.

Answer (score -3):

You consider Ultipa Graph. ([www.ultipa.com](http://www.ultipa.com)). It is not a free / open source graph database but it is not expensive and it is really super fast.

https://www.ultipa.com/article/benchmarks/ultipa-graph-benchmark-report

I have a business interest in the product I am recommending as I am the EMEA sales manager of Ultipa. Because of that, contact me in case you need more information or want a free cloud tier to try our #graphdatabase